# spivak Calculus excercise 5.1 limits.

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - l|< \epsilon$ for all $x$ satisfying $0 < |x-a| < \delta$

$f(x)=x^4$; $l=a^4$

Answer (score 0):

We can suppose that $a$ is not zero since if $a = 0$ then for $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \epsilon^{1/4}$ and we would be done. So we can safely assume $a$ is not $0$. Thus
\begin{align*}
|x^4 - a^4| &= |(x - a)(x^3 + x^2a + xa^2 + a^3)|. \\
|x^3| &= |(x - a) + a|^3 < (|x - a| + |a|)^3 < (2|a|)^3 = 8|a|^3. \\
|ax^2| &= |a|((x - a) + a))^2 < |a|(|x - a| + |a|)^2 < |a|(2|a|)^2 = 4|a|^3.\\
|xa^2| &= |a|^2 |(x - a) + a)| < |a|^2(|x - a| + |a|) < |a|^2*(2|a|) = 2|a|^3. \\
|a^3| &= |a|^3 \, .
\end{align*}
Thus we have
\begin{align*}
|x^4 - a^4| < |x - a|(8|a|^3 + 4|a|^3 + 2|a|^3 + |a|^3) = |x - a| (15|a|^3).
\end{align*}
Thus for a given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \min\left\{|a|, \frac{\epsilon}{15|a|^3}\right\}$ then this implies: $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ when $|x - a| < \delta$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am having a really hard time reading the post :(.

Comment: @Surya: you can reformat it. Feel free.

Comment: I tried to put $ signs around the equations it wont let me submit because edit needs to have > 10 charecters :|

Comment: @Surya: try again and feel free to add things you need to make it happen

Comment: @LAcarguy You should do it, it is your post.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this 
$(|x - a| + |a|)^3 < (2|a|)^3$